# Setting Extended Properties in Microsoft Graph API using proptags

Tags: python, rest, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to set a property tag according to Graph API documents as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

I am trying to set a extended property on a MailFolder using the patch endpoint as listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The content of the message is:
`{'singleValueExtendedProperties': [{'id': 'String 0x10F4000B', 'value': 'true'}]}`

However, i always get the result that indicates it fails due to a property value error:
`{"error": {"code": "ErrorFolderSavePropertyError", "message": "The folder save operation failed due to invalid property values.", "innerError": { "request-id": "GUID", "date": "2019-11-12T19:44:02"}}}`

Looking at the rules around MAPI and setting its values, it is trying to set the tag 0x10F4 using type 0x000B which is boolean. However, the extended properties only excepts strings. I am not sure how to set a boolean value into the value field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second half for the type goes where the string value is. So to post this, it will become 
`{'singleValueExtendedProperties': [{'id': 'boolean 0x10F4', 'value': '**true**'}]}1